# Append CSVs in folder; how to skip / delete first rows in each file

Tags: powerbi, append, powerbi-datasource

I have 25 CSV files in a folder linked as my data source. The 1st row in each file contains just the file name in column A, followed by the column headers in the 2nd row (this is how the files are generated and sent to me; I do not have access to the database).
[CSVs first 2 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG5gC.png)

When I remove the first row of the sample file, then promote headers, then Close & Apply, I get a list of errors which are essentially the redundant column header rows in each of the subsequent 24 files in the folder.
[Error List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvL9t.png)

Upon suggestion, I changed the end of the first Applied Step in *Transform Sample File* from QuoteStyle.None]) to QuoteStyle.Csv]). This did not solve and didn't seem to change anything.

Another suggestion was that I could just proceed with the errors; filter as needed but that it wouldn't be a problem. This seems risky/sloppy to me, but maybe it's fine and I'm just a nervous newb?

Many thanks for any input!

Comment: Can you please check this help or not- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZx5V2RPtY8

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. This did not solve my problem, but I was able to solve by 1) removing rows & promoting headers in the Transform Sample File step, and then 2) removing final "Changed Type Column1" in the resulting query table. Very simple, just eluded me for quite a while.

Comment: ErinF, Nice to see it solved somehow :)